# Set a write timeout HttpsUrlConnection/HttpUrlConnection/UrlConnection in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to set a write timeout on a UrlConnection?

I could manage it with conscrypt:

```
this.setSSLSocketFactory(new DelegatingSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()) {
            @Override
            protected SSLSocket configureSocket(SSLSocket sslSocket) throws IOException {
                if(sslSocket instanceof OpenSSLSocketImpl) {
                    OpenSSLSocketImpl conscryptSocket = (OpenSSLSocketImpl) sslSocket;
                    conscryptSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(writeTimeoutMs);
                }
                return super.configureSocket(sslSocket);
            }
        });
```

but that feels dodgy.

Does a better solution exist?

Comment: There are no TLS or HTTP or HTTPS or TCP write timeouts in Java, or indeed in most operating systems.

Comment: um I do know that okhttp has a write timeout so that is not true.